# onApplyWindowInsets is not called in CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine

Tags: wear-os, watch-face-api

I am developing a watch face using **CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine**

I need to detect if watch is round or square.

I overrided **onApplyWindowInsets**, but it is not called.

Shall I set a specific listener or something like that?

Comment: The onApplyWindowInsets should be called. Can you post your code?

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, `onApplywindowInsets` only gets called when you're using `Theme.DeviceDefault`, or a theme descending from it. It won't get called if you're using a completely custom theme.

So in the manifest for your watch face, your `application` tag needs to look something like this:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault" >
```

Or if you have a theme for the watch face service, that will override it.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, onApplyWindowInsets is not called unless android:

`isScrollContainer = "true"`

is set to any view in layout.